# Spaces in bash variable path name

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, sequence

What's the proper way to do this?

```
$ export SUBLPKG=~/"Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages"
$ cd $SUBLPKG
-bash: cd: /Users/$ME/Library/Application: No such file or directory


$ export SUBLPKG=~/"Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages"
$echo $SUBLPKG
/Users/$ME/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages
$ cd $SUBLPKG
-bash: cd: /Users/$ME/Library/Application\: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7):

The proper way is to quote the variable while expanding else word splitting would happen on whitespaces:

```
export SUBLPKG=~/"Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages"
cd "$SUBLPKG"
```

You might also want to refer to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) in the manual.

Also refer to Word Splitting [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: Can anyone insert punctuation into this answer? It is unreadable.